# Thunderbird cannot open "Kontakte". How to get rid of that error message?

Tags: thunderbird, address-book

In each case shortly after the start of the Thunderbird email I read:

> There was a problem opening the address book "Kontakte" - the message returned was: Cannot open book: Source already loaded!

What does this mean? What must I do? I do not need those contacts!

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem using [this advice](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1844827).

Basically, I had to disable EDS integration add-on in Thunderbird.

1. Click "Tools" -> "Add-ons" menu item.
2. Select "Extensions".
3. Select "EDS Contact Integration".
4. Press the "Disable" button.
5. Click "File" -> "Quit" menu item.
6. Launch Thunderbird again.

Of course, I have no idea whatsoever of what EDS integration may be.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer - it's very nice you summarized the link you used, as the links tend to break sooner or later. Also, it's obviously a good idea to include the link to your sources. I fixed that link for you - if you want to make your posts even better, please take a look at formatting toolbar on top of editor